# Traveling from the airport to Mexico City

Tags: airport-transfer, mexico-city

There are several options for traveling from the airport to Mexico City:

- Uber
- Metro
- Buses
- Taxis

Which is most convenient when traveling with a child? Also I speak Spanish.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I would encourage you to [edit] your post to specify the location where are you starting from, and the terms by which you would define *convenient*, such as number of transfers, walking distance, or  handling of luggage.

Answer (score 3):

**A taxi, particularly if you have luggage.** It might take longer than the metro because Mexico city is often congested but you, your child and luggage will get all delivered point-to-point.

The metro is definitely cheaper though and there are children using it all the time. Any bags that you take from the airport station into the metro will get inspected though and cannot be too large or it will be quite cumbersome to go through the turning gates. You may also need to get transportation from the exit metro station to exactly where you are going.

Comment: Would a taxi be better than Uber?  I tend to prefer the latter in unfamiliar cities.

Comment: Definitely, but make sure it is an official taxi as there are plenty of taxi scams in Mexico City. Finding an official taxi in the airport is easy and you will get to know the rate before leaving the terminal. IIRC, there is a table with prices for going to each *zone*.

Comment: @Itai Can you expand on your comment that taxi is definitely better than Uber?  Here in Tijuana the opinion seems to be other way around for visitors to the city (although that may be because of the proximity to the border)